# unable to connect DREVO bluetooth keyboard to RPi3

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

I'm trying to connect a DREVO Bluetooth keyboard to the RPi3 B rev2 running Raspbian 9.

With the keyboard in pairing mode, I am able to use the Bluetooth menu, scan and find the device to add, and a dialog pops up saying "connected successfully", but the keyboard is still in pairing mode (led blinks fast) and it does not work.

In dmesg I find a lot of messages:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: security requested but not available
```

Running `btmon` during the pairing I find these messages:

```
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                                                                       [hci0] 29.773843
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2
        Handle: 0x001c
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                       [hci0] 29.870713
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x001c
        Error: Insufficient Authentication (0x05)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                                                                       [hci0] 29.871379
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2
        Handle: 0x001c
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                           [hci0] 29.919458
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                       [hci0] 29.968211
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x001c
        Error: Insufficient Authentication (0x05)
```

repeated over and over.

When I try to do the same with `bluetoothctl` this is what I get:

```
[bluetooth]# info FF:A6:38:C5:3D:A8
Device FF:A6:38:C5:3D:A8
    Name: DREVO
    Alias: DREVO
    Appearance: 0x03c1
    Icon: input-keyboard
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Quintic Corp.             (0000fee9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Unknown                   (0000ff00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v093Ap2801d0001
[bluetooth]# connect FF:A6:38:C5:3D:A8
Attempting to connect to FF:A6:38:C5:3D:A8
[CHG] Device FF:A6:38:C5:3D:A8 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device FF:A6:38:C5:3D:A8 Name: DREV0
[CHG] Device FF:A6:38:C5:3D:A8 Alias: DREV0
[DEL] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0008
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Generic Attribute Profile
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0009/char000a
    00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Manufacturer Name String
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0009/char000c
    00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Model Number String
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0009/char000e
    00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Serial Number String
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0009/char0010
    00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Hardware Revision String
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0009/char0012
    00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Firmware Revision String
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0009/char0014
    00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Software Revision String
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0009/char0016
    00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    PnP ID
[DEL] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0009
    0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Device Information
[DEL] Descriptor
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0040/char0041/desc0043
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0040/char0041
    00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Battery Level
[DEL] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0040
    0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Battery Service
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0044/char0045
    0000ffe6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Unknown
[DEL] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0044
    0000ff00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Unknown
[DEL] Descriptor
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0047/char0048/desc004a
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[DEL] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0047/char0048
    0000fec9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Apple, Inc.
[DEL] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_A6_38_C5_3D_A8/service0047
    0000fee9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Quintic Corp.
[CHG] Device FF:A6:38:C5:3D:A8 Connected: no
```

not sure what's going on

Comment: "security requested but not available" and "Error: Insufficient Authentication (0x05)" sound like the RPi expects the keyboard to provide a pin during pairing. Can you try running `bluetoothctl --agent=NoInputNoOutput`?

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll try as soon as I get home. But I successfully paired a BT mouse (Apple Magic Mouse) which also doesn't require a pin to pair, so I don't think that's the explanation.

Comment: I'm not certain it would actually help. However, there's a difference: a mouse physically cannot provide a pin code. A keyboard can. I've actually seen BT keyboards which required typing a pin on them when pairing.